# Bootstrap 4 - Customize Progress Bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 alpha. How can I customize (Eg: removing border-radius, changing bar base color, filled color etc...)?

Tried with below code.. but it is not working though :(

**[LIVE DEMO](http://codepen.io/areddyprasad/pen/LpbKPY)**

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="b4-test">
  <progress class="progress" value="75" max="100">75%</progress>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.b4-test{
  padding:50px;
  width:500px;
  margin:50px auto;
  text-align:center;
  background:#ccc;
}

progress{
  border-radius:0 !important;
  background-image:none !important;
  background-color:red !important;
  color:green !important;
  height:50px;
}
```

Comment: `<progress>` is browser dependent element. On Firefox it will look entirely different than on Chrome

Comment: **@Justinas**.. Thanks for the answer... that means, I dont have any option to change the '<progress>' bar for Bootstrap 4? :(

Comment: yes you can change it but not sure in chrome but in firefox you can

Comment: For chrome you can also use -- **.progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value** property to set custom css properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this snippet in `Firefox`

This snippet will work in `Firefox` only..

**Edit**

I have also created plunker to show in `Firefox` please check this

[Firefox Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/b4ab6kre9Q0DE4vBXsGI?p=preview)

```css
.b4-test {
  padding: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ccc;
}
.progress[value] {
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
.progress[value]::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="b4-test">
  <progress class="progress" value="75" max="100">75%</progress>
</div>
```

For **Chrome** check the below plunker

check this [Chrome Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aSR68k96ebfQVD0nMh58?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks **@Amit singh**... its almost working in Chrome.. but sorry, I do not have firefox browser access

Comment: you are welcome @Reddy no matter with firefox if you want it to work in firefox please check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks **@Amit**.... Mozilla plunker example is working is Chrome but not Chrome plunker :)

Some how, it is working in Chrome ... Thanks for the Answer

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem, but I just wanted to change the color of the progress part.

My progress bar is the following:

```
<progress class="progress progress-custom" value="25" max="100">25%</progress>
```

I added the custom class `progress-custom` to the Object and defined some CSS for it.

```
.progress-custom[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: #FE6502;
}

.progress-custom[value]::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: #FE6502;
}

.progress-custom[value]::-ms-fill {
  background-color: #FE6502;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 0\0) {
  .progress-custom .progress-bar {
    background-color: #FE6502;
  }
}
```

These additional CSS will change the color of the progress part. I also tested with the border-radius, it is also possible to change this to whatever you want.

I just tested it really quickly: Chrome and Firefox were affected by the changes, IE had the right color, but the border-radius did not work.